# Creating Junction from mapped NAS

Tags: windows-server-2008, junction

I need to create a junction "test" on `J:\` (which is a Windows partition) which should refer to `K:\folder1\folder2\folder3` (mapped network drive).

I cd into `J:\` and ran the command `mklink /J k:\folder1\folder2\folder3 test` but it returned the error:

```
Local volumes are required to complete the operation.
```

Can't I create a junction for mapped network drives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Can't we create *junction* for mapped network drives?

No, that is not supported. Junctions can only be created to drives **on the same computer**.

You can create a *Directory symbolic link* instead:

```
mklink /d k:\folder1\folder2\folder3 test
```

Notes:

- `/d` Create a Directory symbolic link. (default is file)
- By default, only Administrators can create symbolic links.

  The security setting 'Create symbolic links' can be granted at:

  `Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\`

[image]

Source [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.